# How to get the filters page?

Tags: php, magento, filter

I needed to create 3 filters in combobox works correctly, however was unable to make a condiçãod and display only the options that exist within each category.

Example: In the native filter magento if you have 3 choices but only 1 option is selected, the magento shows only 1 option in my shows 3.

Below my code example:

```
<?php
$attr1='filtro1';
$attributeInfo1 = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($attr1)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId1 = $attributeInfo1->getAttributeId();
$attribute1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId1);
$attributeOptions1 = $attribute1->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
?>
<select onchange="submit()" name="filtro1">
<option value="">Selecione um...</option>
<?php
    foreach($attributeOptions1 as $filtro1){?>
        <option <?php if($_GET['filtro1'] == $filtro1['value']){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>value="<?php echo $filtro1['value'];?>">
            <?php echo $filtro1['label'];?>
        </option>
<?php       
    }
?>
</select>
```

I need to make a condition, but can not capture the filters page.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State');
foreach ($_filters as $_filter){
    print_r($_filter);
}
?>
```

But he returns with empty arrays

```
Array ( ) catalog/layer/state.phtmlArray ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to resolve, making a workaround, below the new code:

```
<?php
$category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($category_id);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$cont = 0;
foreach ($collection as $_product){             
    $filtrated1 .= $_product->getData('filter1');
    $cont++;
    if($cont == 1){
        $filtrated1 .= ',';
    }
}           
$filtrated1 = array_unique(explode(',',$filtrated1));

$attr1='filter1';
$attributeInfo1 = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($attr1)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId1 = $attributeInfo1->getAttributeId();
$attribute1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId1);
$attributeOptions1 = $attribute1->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
?>

<select onchange="submit()" name="filter1">
    <option value="">Selecione um...</option>
    <?php
        foreach($attributeOptions1 as $filter1){
            foreach($filtrated1 as $show1){
                if($filter1['value'] == $show1){?>
                    <option <?php if($_GET['filter1'] == $filter1['value']){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>value="<?php echo $filter1['value'];?>">
                        <?php echo $filter1['label'];?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Basically I listed the products and options selected them and did not show whether or condition.